# ProxyCommand for ssh jump failed for one machine but works for others

Tags: server, ssh

I have `~/.ssh/config` file on my local machine as:

```
Host head
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xx.xxx.xx

Host machine1
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null

Host machine2
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null

Host machine3
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null

Host machine4
  User Marry
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
  IdentityFile /home/Marry/ssh_head_keys/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand  ssh head nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

I can successfully do `ssh machine1`, `ssh machine2`, `ssh machine3` my local machine, and go to machine 1-3, but for machine4, the command `ssh machine4` failed with:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

How could this happen?

**UPDATE**: follow muru's advice, remove `2> /dev/null`, I got the message when ssh to machine4:

```
bash: nc: command not found
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Maybe remove the `2> /dev/null` and see if an error shows.

Comment: @muru, please check my update

Comment: That's weird because the `nc` command is executed on the jump host, i.e. on `head`, so why does it work for the other three hosts then? I'd also check if it is "manually" possible (in two separate steps) to connect from `localhost → head` and then `head → machine4`. Perhaps an issue with the keys between `head` and `machine4`.